# Can't ssh to my ubuntu machine using global ip address

Tags: ssh

I've gone to my router settings and added port forwarding for port 22 to my linux machine. However, when I now type 
       ssh @ 
from another computer (the terminal of my mac), it says operation timed out. I've used grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config to confirm that port 22 is infact the port ssh uses on my linux. Am I missing some thing?

Comment: Your situation is not clear to me. You have some home network doing NAT on the router. You told that router to forward port 22 to a linux machine inside your home network. You are able to ssh to your machine from the internet. You are not able to ssh to your machine from another host inside your network using the public ip address of your router. You are able to ssh to that box using its internal ip address. Is all that correct? - If this is the case see the duplicate link. :)

Comment: You guys are right.. the other question does help me understand what the problem is. Thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure you are able to ping IP and telnet from your remote machine...

Also make sure you are able to ssh locally and Iptables is configured or disabled.

Make sure your ssh service is running and port is listening.

`nmap` and `netstat` command will be helpful

```
$ nmap mylinuxserverip.com
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh >> should be open
```

Comment: If he has forwarded the port ping might not be of use, since the ping will be answered by the router, not the ssh server.